# cannot rename files when saving

Tags: xubuntu, rename

I am using xubuntu 13.10. Since the last update, when I am saving files I cannot rename other files, there are missing buttons in context menu like rename, cut, copy, etc...

let`s say I edited the file named style.css in firefox, and I want to save it, but i do not want to overwrite the original, I want to rename the original for ex: style_orig.css and save the edited file with the name style.css. for doing that I must open thunar, navigate to that file, and rename it, after that, I can save the file from firefox.

---

let`s reformulate this question:

if I want to overwrite a file, but preserve the original, then I must make a copy of the original.

Well, I can not do this when saving the file from the application, I must open thunar and navigate to that file which is an additional task I have to do. It`s a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a file which is already present on disk and you are currently editing it, it is better to "Save As" the file than the procedure you are following. This will preserve the previous copy of the file and create a new copy with the new name you specify while saving it afresh.

Comment: Sorry if I made my self unclear,
I do not want to save the file with a new name, I want to save it wit the same name, I just want to make a copy of the original.

Comment: @BotondVajna: You could do even that in the same manner, just keep the copy in some other location.